# Joining the array elements and then removing spaces from result

Tags: perl

I have certain result from a SELECT query from PSQL in a way that, every table is coming out with a leading space.

I am then joining the elements through pipe as below:

```
my @tables = @_;
my $table_list = join "|",@tables;
```

I am getting the result as:

```
TABLE LIST IS: NEW_ENTRY| SAMPLE| NEW_ENTRY| SAMPLE
```

I want the output as:

```
TABLE LIST IS: NEW_ENTRY|SAMPLE|NEW_ENTRY|SAMPLE
```

I tried with map, chomp but dont know what i am missing.

Comment: Consider `map` function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us how you get the values in `@tables`. The obvious solution is to remove the whitespace, but I would look at the data in the database. `chomp` removes newlines, not spaces.

Comment: @Arkadiy: # Shell Script to run a sql command from command line
. /.profile 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
DBUSER=$1
DBPASS=$2
SQLCMD=$3
PGPASSWORD=$DBPASS psql -d $dbname -h krh7posdb -U $dbuser -t <<EOF
$SQLCMD;
EOF


And then, 

my $cmd = "runsql.sh $LocalDBUser $LocalDBPassword 'select TABLE_NAME from SOME_TABLE where UPDATE_TIME > SYNC_TIME' 2>&1"; 

my $ret = qx/$cmd/;


RESULT IS:

2018-06-18 18:08:22.837937 < APP > get_updated_tables(): get updated table success:  NEW_ENTRY
 SAMPLE
 NEW_ENTRY
 SAMPLE

Comment: Please edit your attempt with map into the question (chomp is not suitable, I think). Provide the input and the output.

Comment: Would you suggest the map operation ON ? 

    map { s/^\s+|\s+$//g; } @tables; OR
    map { s/^\s+|\s+$//g; } $table_list;
 
OR Any other syntax,if missed out.

Comment: I'd suggest map on the list, not on the string :). Oh, and what is that regexp? Should it not be `s/\s/_/r` (forgot `r` initiallly)?  (please, please edit your code into the question!)

Comment: The best approach is to fix the data in your database so that the `table_name` column does not include those extra spaces. And fix whatever populates that column as well.

Answer (score 5):

You need

```
my $table_list = join '|', map { s/^\s+//r } @tables
```

But as **simbabque** says in his comment, you should investigate where these spaces are coming from and fix the underlying problem. It may be that the database has been populated incorrectly or the error may be in the code you have written to read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
( my $table_list = join( "|", @tables )) =~ s/\s+//g;
```

You can apply a substitution after an assignment if you place the assignment in parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to run splite once again and then again join the contents.
chomp didn't work here, because ( I think space is at the front) secondly if you want to go by map you can.

```
my $table=" NEW_ENTRY| SAMPLE| NEW_ENTRY| SAMPLE";
my @arr=split(' ',$table);
my $arr1=join('',@arr);
```

OUTPUT:
NEW_ENTRY|SAMPLE|NEW_ENTRY|SAMPLE